# Form of elements of a Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, gr.group-theory

How can we write the elements of a free Lie algebra? Is there any reference concerning  this subject?

Answer (score 9):

The key words are "Lyndon words". A reference is Free Lie Algebras by C. Reutenauer.

Comment: @Bruce: Probably it's helpful to include more details about the book http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1231799, along with the later short expository article http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2035110

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as was said previously the key is Lyndon words and the reference is Reutenauer's book "Free Lie algebras". Your free Lie algebra reads $L_R<X>$ where $X$ is an alphabet (i.e. a set) and $R$ is a unitary ring. If your (free Lie) algebra is given by $L(V)$ where $V$ is a free module over $R$, take for $X$ any basis of $V$. Now you need :

1. a total order on $X$ and its associated lexicographic (total) order $\prec_{lex}$

   the set $Lyn(X)$ of Lyndon words which are strict minima of their conjugacy class or, equivalently,
   $$
   Lyn(X)=\{w\in X^+| (w=uv\ ;\ u\in X^+)\Longrightarrow w\prec_{lex} v\} 
   $$
   where $X^+$  is the set of non empty words on $X$ which can be phased as 
   >Lyndon words is the set of non empty words that are smaller than all their proper right factors.

   as a lemma, one shows that every Lyndon word $l$ which is not a letter can be written (in sevral ways in general) as $l=l_1l_2$ with $l_1\prec_{lex}l_2$, one notes $\sigma(l)$ the factorisation with $|l_2|$ maximal. This is called the _canonical factorisation_

   The Lyndon basis $(P_l)_{l\in Lyn(X)}$ ($L(V)$ is a free module over $R$ and this basis is a linear basis of $L(V)$) is constructed by

   1. $P_x=x$ if $x\in X$

      $P_l=[P_{l_1},P_{l_2}]$ otherwise and with $\sigma(l)=(l_1,l_2)$

   **Decomposition** Every Lie polynomial "begins" lexicographically by a Lyndon word and one can show that $P_l=l+\ \mathrm{higher\ terms}$. You get therefore

   1. a test to know whether a polynomial is Lie (independant of the characteristic and even of the ring $R$)

      an algorithm for the decomposition

**Addition.** This algorithm has many applications. One of them is to compute the *multiplication table* of the Free Lie algebra (combinatorial problem still open) i.e. the structure constants 
$$
[P_{l_1},P_{l_2}]=\sum_{l\in Lyn(X)}\gamma_{l_1,l_2}^l\,P_l
$$

Answer (score 3):

"Lie Algebras: Theory and Algorithms" by Willem A. De Graaf has a chapter dealing with the more general problem of explicit construction of a basis of a finitely presented Lie algebra (free Lie algebra modulo an ideal), perhaps it is what you are looking for.